# PHP: convert time to device timezone

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a database table where I store a date `NOW()`, and the time is set two hours behind me. My timezone is UTC+2, and my phpMyAdmin database is using 'Africa/Accra' or 'Artic/Reykjavik' - GMT.

It’s fine if my database is using this as default, but when I try to convert the time to the users timezone, nothing happens.

This is what I have tried:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Accra"); // Also tried with GMT

$timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
$feed_time = '2014-05-20 19:27:52';

$schedule_date = new DateTime($feed_time, new DateTimeZone($timezone) );
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("$feed_time UTC"));

echo $newdate;
```

This echo out: `2014-05-20 19:27:52`, so no difference.

How can I convert the time so it would be the same as the device default timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `$schedule_date`. You create it with your new values but never actually use it. You still use the old data.

```
$schedule_date = new DateTime($feed_time, new DateTimeZone($timezone) );
echo $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Also, you need to set your date/time first and then change the timezone. This is because your date/time is in UTC so you need to start there. Then you can change the timezone accordingly.

```
$original_date = new DateTime('2014-05-20 19:27:52', new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
$original_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Accra'));
echo $original_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$schedule_date = new DateTime('2014-05-20 19:27:52', new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
$schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2014-05-20 19:27:52
2014-05-20 21:27:52
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/raHMTa)

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick answer. But its still the same date as before. The time dosnt change, but if I try with `Europa/London`, the date is changing. But not with GMT

Comment: There we go! Thanks so much @John Conde :D